# Can not use global styles in styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am trying to setup global styles in react-native. 
I have imported

`import {injectGlobal} from 'styled-components';`

and have

```
class XoxoContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Xoxo {...this.props} />
  }
}


injectGlobal`
  font-family: '20'
`;
```

But I keep getting `styledComponents.injectGlobals is not a function.` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a styles.js file like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    view_flex_one_white: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: white
}});
```

and use this anywhere in your app with import

```
    import {styles} from "...link to file/styles";

      render(){
         return(
           <View style={styles.view_flex_one_white}>

           </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That function is not part of the library on react-native [according to this Github issue.](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1786) That's why it keeps saying that it's not a function, because it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a js file with this pattern:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var myStyle = React.StyleSheet.create({
   style1: { },
   style2: { }
)}

module.exports = myStyle;
```

your component js use require to use that style sheet

```
var customStyle = require('../the/path/to/commonStyleSheet');
```

Use now like this:

```
<View style = {customStyle .style1} />
```